# save live audio streaming to wave file in java

Tags: java, sockets

i getting audio from android client with DatagramSocket in java server
now i want save audio that has been receive to wave file.

java server code is:

```
private static void receiveAudioFromAndroidClient() {
    try {
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(50005);
        serverSocket1 = new ServerSocket(8072);


        byte[] receiveData = new byte[4096];
        // ( 1280 for 16 000Hz and 3584 for 44 100Hz (use AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat) to get the correct size)

        format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, false);

        while (status == true) {
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                    receiveData.length);

            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

            ByteArrayInputStream baiss = new ByteArrayInputStream(receivePacket.getData());

            ais = new AudioInputStream(baiss, format, receivePacket.getLength());


            // A thread solve the problem of chunky audio
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    toSpeaker(receivePacket.getData());
                }
            }).start();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use `AudioSystem` to write audio data to file, like this:

```
AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(...);
AudioSystem.write(ais, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new File("audio.wav"));
```

Comment: can you write me the example in full form? size file is 5kB and not play audio, i wanna save complete audio